# StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException:

Tags: redis

Can I get help understanding this error message and where I should look for the root cause

StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing GET (5000ms), next: GET ReviewStatSession|cuuchrwt1pattdmytjfveu55, inst: 3, qu: 0, qs: 218, aw: False, rs: TryParseResult, ws: Idle, in: 65536, in-pipe: 90112, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint:

redis-17006.predc30.production.int:17006, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 9 of 10 available, clientName: PWEB184NTV, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=52,Free=32715,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.1.30.38891 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts) at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.StringGet(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags) at ReviewStat.RedisPageStatePersister.Load() at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.T ExecuteSyncImpl[T](StackExchange.Redis.Message, StackExchange.Redis.ResultProcessor`1[T], StackExchange.Redis.ServerEndPoint)() at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.T ExecuteSync[T](StackExchange.Redis.Message, StackExchange.Redis.ResultProcessor`1[T], StackExchange.Redis.ServerEndPoint)()
at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.StackExchange.Redis.RedisValue StringGet(StackExchange.Redis.RedisKey, StackExchange.Redis.CommandFlags)()
at ReviewStat.RedisPageStatePersister.Void Load()()
at System.Web.UI.Page.System.Object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()()

Comment: Have you taken a look at the article linked in the error to see if any of the situations described therein might apply to how you're using the library?

Comment: Yes but not familiar enough with the product.

Comment: Seems like the works are over burdened

Comment: This helped me, I did not have targetFramework in my httpRuntime tag in my web.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/993854/all-redis-commands-timing-out-when-using-azure-cac.html